# ExtensionDataObject not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer, binaryformatter

Oi!

I'm having issues serializing my session state. We have 2 components, our WCF and Web. Based on our AdministrationPartial.cs and Administration.svc we generate "Administration.cs" code for our web project with the following .bat file :

```
svcutil.exe http://wcf_url.local/Administration.svc?wsdl /r:"{Path}\{Namespace}.dll" /d:"{Path}\{Namespace}\Code"
```

I removed the personal data from the above statement and replaced it with {path} and {namespace}. The Administration.cs will be inside the Code map.

In the Partial we have :

```
[Serializable]
public partial class MyObject
{
    <Some code>
}
```

It generated the following code :

```
namespace {mynamespace}
{
          using System.Runtime.Serialization

          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
          [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
          [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="MyObject", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/{namespace}")]
          public partial class MyObject : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
          {
                    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
                    ...... generated code
```

What am i doing wrong?

Tim

EDIT : Actual error is : `Type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject' in Assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  1) Are you asking why Microsoft did not apply the `[Serializable]`  attribute to the .Net type `ExtensionDataObject`? 2) Are you using both the data contract serializer and `BinaryFormatter` to serialize your class `MyObject`?

Comment: State the main issue you encounter.

Comment: I encouter the following error : Type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject' in Assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: What are you doing when you encounter this error?  Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that generates the error?  (It looks as though you are doing binary serialization, is that correct?)

Comment: Is your question, "how can I serialize a class, using `BinaryFormatter`, that implements `IExtensibleDataObject` and contains a field of type `ExtensionDataObject`, when the latter is not marked as `[Serializable]`?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your question is, **How can I create a class that is `[Serializable]` for `BinaryFormatter` and also implements `IExtensibleDataObject` for `DataContractSerializer`?**

The answer is that this does not work out of the box since, as you have noticed, [`ExtensionDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.extensiondataobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not marked as serializable.  Nevertheless it can be done with a bit of extra coding.  For whatever reason Microsoft chose to make `ExtensionDataObject` a completely opaque pointer, with no public properties or other ways to access the data therein.  Except that it *is* possible to access the data inside by re-serializing to XML using [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This suggests a way to make your `MyObject` class serializable: store the extension data in a proxy container field that implements [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and, internally, serializes and deserializes the extension data to XML.

The following proxy wrapper accomplishes this task:

```
[Serializable]
public struct ExtensionDataObjectSerializationProxy : ISerializable
{
    public static implicit operator ExtensionDataObjectSerializationProxy(ExtensionDataObject data) { return new ExtensionDataObjectSerializationProxy(data); }

    public static implicit operator ExtensionDataObject(ExtensionDataObjectSerializationProxy proxy) { return proxy.ExtensionData; }

    private readonly System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get { return extensionDataField; } }

    [DataContract(Name = "ExtensionData", Namespace = "")]
    sealed class ExtensionDataObjectSerializationContractProxy : IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        #region IExtensibleDataObject Members

        public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public ExtensionDataObjectSerializationProxy(ExtensionDataObject extensionData)
    {
        this.extensionDataField = extensionData;
    }

    public ExtensionDataObjectSerializationProxy(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var xml = (string)info.GetValue("ExtensionData", typeof(string));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            var wrapper = DataContractSerializerHelper.LoadFromXML<ExtensionDataObjectSerializationContractProxy>(xml);
            extensionDataField = (wrapper == null ? null : wrapper.ExtensionData);
        }
        else
        {
            extensionDataField = null;
        }
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (ExtensionData != null)
        {
            var xml = DataContractSerializerHelper.GetXml(new ExtensionDataObjectSerializationContractProxy { ExtensionData = this.ExtensionData });
            info.AddValue("ExtensionData", xml);
        }
        else
        {
            info.AddValue("ExtensionData", (string)null);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class DataContractSerializerHelper
{
    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, DataContractSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter))
            {
                (serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T))).WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(string xml, DataContractSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml ?? ""))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
        {
            return (T)(serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T))).ReadObject(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then manually modify your `MyObject` class as follows:

```
public partial class MyObject : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{
    private ExtensionDataObjectSerializationProxy extensionDataField; // Use the proxy not ExtensionDataObject directly

    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler answer see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2010/02/15/extensiondataobject-is-not-marked-as-serializable.aspx

Just mark the private ExtensionDataObject as non serialized:

```
[NonSerialized]
private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
```